# Is there a way in 2022 to remove factory reset option on android device

Tags: settings, factory-reset

So I’ve Removed some bloatware like the browser google play store etc. and like you all are aware a simple factory reset brings them all back , the first solution I thought of was to remove the settings app but that’s not convenient at all (although it may work) . I’m trying to find a way to keep setting app however remove the factory reset option , would anybody have a code for such thing ? Or any alternative opinion is welcome. Thank you I can use any advice I can get

Answer (score 1):

Make script to debloat and run it after every factory reset...

like this one

https://github.com/jasineri/android-bloatware